# Call external program from python and get its output

Tags: python, call, subprocess

I want to call a program (`.exe`), which is written in C++ and compiled, from Python. The executable takes as input two files and returns a score.

I need to do this for multiple files. So, I would like to write a small script in python which loops over multiple files, passes them to the executable and gets back the values.

Now, I have done my search and I know about SWIG and Boost::Python may be an option but I was trying to find if there is an easier way. I do not need to 'extend' the C++ program. I simply want to call it just like I would from a command line and get the returned number.

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919783/python-calling-a-non-python-program-from-python

Comment: @TorelTwiddler that's not what he wants to do -- that answer just returns the return code, not the output of the program.

Comment: The correct duplicate is [What's a good equivalent to python's subprocess.check_call that returns the contents of stdout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924310/whats-a-good-equivalent-to-pythons-subprocess-check-call-that-returns-the-conte)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run an external program and get its output, use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) on Python 2.7+. The example from the docs:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"])
'crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Oct 18  2007 /dev/null\n'
```

`check_call` just returns the return code of the program, not the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) for that.

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['your_program.exe', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
```