# Use Subprocess module to call external app PDFCombine and designate PDFCombine file output

Tags: python, subprocess

I am writing a python script that will be called in a batch file, and in this script I am using the subprocess module to call PDF Combine to combine multiple PDF files into a single document.

```
for unique_id in newUnique_ids:
    subprocess.call(['K:\VALIDATION\Volumetric\Code_SAS\PDF Combine\PDF
    Combine\PDFCombine.exe','K:\VALIDATION\Volumetric\Forecast\MEVV\pdf\mevv.pdf\{0}*.pdf'.format
   (unique_id)])
```

PDF Combine is able to create a new document with all of the pdfs with the unique_id extension, but I receive an error from PDF combine due to the absence of a file name to save this new document under.  How can I specify the file name I want the new document to save to in Python?  The new documents file name would look like this in the code:

```
 'K:\VALIDATION\Volumetric\Forecast\MEVV\pdf\cmb.pdf\{0}.pdf'.format(line)
```

Thank you!

Comment: That's a question answered by pdfcombine's command line help documentation. Its likely just one more parameter in the list you pass in.

Comment: I found the answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919783/python-calling-a-non-python-program-from-python

I was typing the output incorrectly before, and the link above showed me how to designate the output correctly within the subprocess.call statement.